# Is there any Way to Not Get our App Blocked by Twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I have coded a Fine bot which Tweets every 150 seconds `time.sleep(150)` . I have made a APP from twitter with Read / Write Permissions . But after 30 Tweets, Twitter Blocks the Application. So is there any way to Bypass it. ? Or has someone ever Tried bots in Twitter. Their are some grammar Bots, RT's Bot in twitter which has almost 110k Tweets and they tweet every 30 seconds .. How do they bypass the Frame Limit Protection

Specific Error `Restricted from performing write actions` and Code Stops.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) at least don't specify the rate limit rules, only that there's one. But it does state that you can not have duplicate texts. Is that the case possibly? What HTTP Error are you receiving? Since they don't explicitely post the rules that apply to the rate limit, I'd suppose they might have internal algorithms to tell if it's bot-like behaviour, which I'm sure they do not want to allow. Especially if you set up a new app, regulations might be more strict.

**Edit:**

If you're completely certain that you're not firing up too many requests at once (e.g. check with fiddler to make sure), then twitter suggests to get [in touch](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform) and check the email address of the associated account for any mail from the operations team in order to resolve possible misinterpretations.

This also might be useful: [API developers: abuse prevention and security](https://support.twitter.com/articles/79901?lang=en)

Comment: I am using a Random Function in my code to choose amongst 1000 of Lines, some random Line. So, it is possible that Some might have Duplicate Text But as it is tagging Other People. So the tweets are Different .
For example `hey @xyz` and `hey @abc` .. The string hey might be the same but tweet gets differed by @xyz. I get error after every 30 Automated Tweets that "Restricted from performing write actions" .Which means I won't be able to tweet after the Ban

Comment: And the time between two tweets, how much is there? Are you sure a user's session is not triggering multiple tweets?

Comment: The Time Between Two tweets are 5 minutes i.e `time.sleep(300)` . And yes The Tweets are Exactly being Placed After 5 Minutes of Interval with no User Interaction and The session is Opened from Terminal @rdoubleui

Comment: What is the actual response from the API? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: After the Code Stops i get this "Restricted from performing write actions" which means my twitter APP From which i fetched Keys and Secret Keys are Blocked and when i go to apps.twitter.com i see My App got Blocked whose Consumer key, access token , secret keys i was using.

Comment: See my hints in updated posts. You might need to get in touch with them to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same problem with my twitter bot. I basically made a bot to auto-reply to a specific user and ran that script on cron of 1 minute. Got blocked even though my replies weren't spam but AI generated replies from https://qnamaker.ai/
My script is a bit heavy so it is not feasible for me to keep it running 24*7 as it'll create overhead on server system. But since you keep running it(picked that up because of the delay function), one thing you can do is keep changing the time interval in which your bot makes a tweet. Make it random so that it doesn't look scheduled and bot-like.
You can use the random class in python for that.

```
import random
y=random.randint(100,150)
time.sleep(y)
```

This way your code resumes after random intervals of time. This prevented my bot from getting blocked for a long time. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your bot seems to be banned, their algorithms probably flaged your posting as similar to spam accounts.

You should contact Twitter and explain the situation, using the following page:
[Twitter API Policy Support](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform), give them the details of why they should allow your bot to act as you wish.

Comment: Do Twitter Allows Bot when i send them details?

Comment: It will depend on the details you send them and the behaviour of your bot, if you @user to people that don't interact with the bot they probably won't.